# Quadratic equation with SymPy

Tags: sympy

Very strange behaviour of `solve` command in SymPy, when I try to solve quadratic equation with parameter `a`:

```
from sympy import *
x, a = symbols("x a")
eq = Eq(0, (4 - 4*x + x**2)/(4*a**2))
print(solve(eq, x))
print(solve(simplify(eq), x))
```

Output:

```
[2 - sqrt(a**2 - 1)/a, 2 + sqrt(a**2 - 1)/a]
[2]
```

Just `solve` gives two (!) solutions, which depend on `a`. After symplifying it gives only solution `x=2`, which is correct. What happens? Command `solveset` works correctly, but I am interested in using `solve` command. My SymPy version is 1.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `as_numer_denom` which get an expression that starts as an Add but is essentially a Mul. It is being corrected with [this PR](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/22841).